# How to correctly handle an AJAX request using Spring MVC? Why doesn't this example work in my project?

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and AJAX and I have the following problem.

Into a page my application perform this JavaScript function that perform an AJAX GET request:

```
function caricaDettaglioRegione(regioneSelezionata) {
    var codiceRegione = regioneSelezionata.getAttribute("data-reveal-id");
    var nomeRegione = regioneSelezionata.getAttribute("data-nome-regione");
    
    alert("codiceRegione: " + codiceRegione + " - nomeRegione: " + nomeRegione);
    
    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           data: {'codiceRegione' : codiceRegione
                 },
           url: "riepilogoDettaglioRegione",
           contentType:"application/json"
           
        }).done(function(response) {
            alert("DONE");
            
        }).error(function(xhr) {
            alert("ERROR");
            manageError(xhr);
        });
}
```

As you can see in the Http GET request is passed the value of the **codiceRegione** as request paramether (named **codiceRegione**) by this line:

```
           data: {'codiceRegione' : codiceRegione
                 },
```

So now I want to handle this AJAX request and I have implement this controll method into a **@Controller** class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/riepilogoDettaglioRegione", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String riepilogoDettaglioRegione(@RequestParam("codiceRegione") String codiceRegione, Model model) {
    System.out.println("INTO riepilogoDettaglioRegione()");
    
    return "blabla";
}
```

As you can see it handle the GET requesto toward previous resource (**/riepilogoDettaglioRegione**) and I try to retrieve the **codiceRegione** request parameter by **@RequestParam("codiceRegione")**

But it can't work and this method is not performed when the previous AJAX request is performed.

What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: are you sure the URL is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You're explicitly saying that the codiceRegione is a parameter not the request body.

So for that you will need to change your ajax call like:

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "riepilogoDettaglioRegione?codiceRegione=blah",
       contentType:"application/json"

    }).done(function(response) {
        alert("DONE");

    }).error(function(xhr) {
        alert("ERROR");
        manageError(xhr);
    });
```

Or wrap codiceRegione in an object and then change the annotation @RequestParam for @RequestBody.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can I wrap the codiceRegione into an objet?

Comment: Create a new class called for example MyForm and add into it codiceRegione, then change the signature of your controller from @RequestParam("codiceRegione") String codiceRegione to @RequestBody MyForm form that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by myself.
The problem was that the project used Spring Security and that this resource have to be accessible also to not logged user so I have to insert something like this

```
<intercept-url pattern="/riepilogoDettaglioRegione" access="permitAll" />
```

into the authernticationManager configuration into the **spring-security.xml** file.